# Build an iPhone app that store data in google app engine (or similar) cloud server

Tags: ios, google-app-engine

I am thinking of developing an iPhone app that stores data (users, images, and other data) in a cloud server. Which is the best server/system to use? I am just a beginner (I know objective C and I've made some simple iPhone apps) and I don't know much about data storage in cloud servers. Is there some tutorial on the internet?

Comment: I personally like Dropbox. But this is a subjective question with no right answer that will likely be closed.

Comment: check out https://www.parse.com/about/index its made for such apps

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest iCloud just as it is more integrated in the operating system. Specifically here is a good tutorial about using iCloud in iOS apps. As long as you never decide to port to Android, iCloud will work well.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1

Comment: Good point, as long as they never decide to port to Android :)

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev Yes, that would break everything.

Comment: @MarkRobinson thanks for the answer. I just have a simple and maybe stupid question. My app users should register to iCloud to use my app? or it's just transparent, they register their own users in the app (for example with a simple registration form like an email and password) and use it without know they are using iCloud server? Thanks!

Comment: @AndreaBianchi They will get a notice like "app name" would like to store(or sync) your data on iCloud. Yes No.

Comment: another thing. Imagine an App like Instagram, i know Instagram uses Parse to store the pictures and users. My app should store this data and share with other registered users, is that possible with iCloud?

Comment: @MarkRobinson i understand they have to be registered with iCloud... maybe is not what i am looking for, i need something that share the data with other users and maybe in a website...